# How to Deobfuscation Lua Script?

Tags: string, lua, byte, obfuscation, deobfuscation

```
local script= string.dump(
    function()
        print('Hi')
    end
)

buff=""

for v=1,string.len(script) do
    buff=buff..'\\'..string.byte(script,v)
end

print(buff)
```

script turns into byte code, any idea how to reverse it?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot reverse bytecode to Lua source but you can list the VM instructions with `luac -l`.

Comment: LuaDec shuts down every time for decompiler, i know nothing about VM instructions

Answer (score 0):

To find the difference between VM bytecode and Lua bytecode, in VM bytecode there would always be a `\24` in the front.

In this case, this is VM `(virtual machine)` bytecode. This obfuscation thing also uses a `string.dump` function and can be easily reversed.

Here's the modified decompiler version:

```
local script= string.dump(
    function()

      print('Hi')

    end
)
buff=""

for v=1,string.len(script) do
    buff=buff..'\\'..string.byte(script,v)
end
buff = "'"..buff.."'"
print("print("..buff..")")
```

This version just simply uses the `print` function to print the `string.dump` created in the script. The source is clearly visible, and I'm pretty sure this works for all insecure VM obfuscators.